# web api url conflicting with the ravenDb Id format

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, ravendb

I came across a weird problem while working with ravenDb in a Asp.net Web api 2 project. I have a controller called "TasksController" with a route of "api/tasks". Corresponding to this I also have a tasks collection in my ravendb with Ids like "tasks/1000". When you create a new task by http-post, the api creates a new task as expected and redirects to "tasks/{id}" route. However because the Id of the newly created task is "tasks/1029" the redirect URL coming back becomes "../api/tasks/tasks/1029" which obviously does not exist. Any suggestions please?

Code 
post method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Task task)
    {
        task.Notes.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("F"));
        await _repositoryFactory.TaskRepository.SaveTask(task);
        await _repositoryFactory.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect(Url.Link("Get", new {id = task.Id}));

    }
```

Get

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}", Name = "Get")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string id)
    {
        var task = await _repositoryFactory.TaskRepository.GetById(id);
        return Ok(task);

    }
```

POSTMAN - Post request

```
POST /Hoxro.Web.Api/api/tasks/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 86fba9d3-cfcc-4060-226b-1db0eb189c7a

{

  "priority": 1,
  "notes": [
    "02 January 2016 20:52:59"
  ],
  "linkedTasks": [],
  "createdOn": "02/01/2016",
  "assignedTo": "TaskTestUser",
  "matterIds": [],
  "createdBy": "TaskTestUser",
  "completionDate": null,
  "dueDate": null,
  "completed": false
}
```

Result -

```
{
  "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/Hoxro.Web.Api/api/tasks/tasks/1091'.",
  "messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Tasks' that matches the name 'tasks'."
}
```

Correct result should be - `http://localhost/Hoxro.Web.Api/api/tasks/1091`

I know this is because of the RavenDb Id format, but if I do not go with the standard format Its really difficult to load related documents or I just don't know how to?

Answer (score 1):

If you want redirect to the named route you can use [`RedirectToRoute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.redirecttoroute(v=vs.118).aspx) method instead of manually generation redirection url.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody]Task task)
{
    task.Notes.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("F"));
    await _repositoryFactory.TaskRepository.SaveTask(task);
    await _repositoryFactory.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToRoute("Get", new {id = task.Id});
}
```

Also the "right way" is illustrated in [web api overview](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) where url add to the response header:

```
[Route("api/books")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Book book)
{
    // Validate and add book to database (not shown)

    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

    // Generate a link to the new book and set the Location header in the response.
    string uri = Url.Link("GetBookById", new { id = book.BookId });
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Header thing is correct, however I think the problem will remain, as Url.link will produce book/book/123 for example. This more because of Ravndb than anything else. -- cheers though

Comment: You are looking at request header. Url.Link compose URL and I think it concatenates with your currrent url. Did you try to use `RedirectToRoute` or second solution? Is it completes with the same result 'http://localhost/Hoxro.Web.Api/api/tasks/tasks/1091'?